# permission denied error on command "cd" IN een bash script

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts, php

During a (long) PHP session I make an SQL dump of the database after each major change and store the name of the dump file in `$_SESSION['lastbackup']`. At the end of the session I want to remove all generated dumps except the last one (the name of which is then in `$_SESSION['lastbackup']` ) with following script:

`~/bin/removeoldbackups.sh`:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 # remove all files in directory $1 which are part of file pool $2, 
 except when filename == $3
 # arguments:
 # 1     directory path
 # 2     filepool (with wild cards)
 # 3     name of file NOT to be removed
 if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
 #       no 3rd parameter; 'none' assumed
         keep="none"
 else
         keep=$3
 fi
 cd "$1"
 for  f in $2
 do
         if [ "$f" != "$keep" ]; then
                 rm "$f"
         fi
 done
 exit
```

When I run it from the command prompt with:

```
removeoldbackups.sh  /media/fritzmedia/Elements/ubuntubackup mdvlp2*.sql  mdvlp20161225-23:20:09.sql
```

it works fine. However when I run it from my `.php` webpage

```
shell_exec( '~/bin/removeoldbackups.sh
        /media/fritzmedia/Elements/ubuntubackup ' . 
        'mdvlp2*.sql '.
        $_SESSION['lastbackup'] );
```

I get the following error:

```
sh: 2: /media/fritzmedia/Elements/ubuntubackup: Permission denied
```

(I've tried `exec` instead of `shell_exec`: makes no difference.)
I guess (as it says) this means that it is not a permission problem of executing the script, but of accessing (some part of the path to) the backup files.

Additional info:

- `fritzmedia` is an external drive mounted on `/media`.
- File owner for `/media` is `root:root`; for `fritzmedia` and from there downwards it is `www-data:root`.
- Permissions for `/media` down until the intended files: `0777`.

The `removeoldbackups.sh` script is in `~/bin`; owner `root:root`; permission `0755`.

The backup files are created by a call from a PHP file:

```
exec ( 'mysqldump -u -sqluser- -sqlpw- ' . $dbn . ' > ' . $dumpnaam );
```

Comment: I think `for f in $2` means something other than you think. The for-in loop expects an array, not a directory to read file names from. Perhaps you need something like `for f in $(ls -1 $2)`?

Comment: @Jos: [Useless use of `ls` award](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#ls)

Comment: What is the full path to `~/bin`? What user runs the script from command prompt (www-data or root or someone else)? Try running it as user www-data `sudo -H -u www-data ~/bin/removeoldbackups.sh`

Comment: Thanks. But  for f in $2  works when i run the script from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `sh: 2: /media/fritzmedia/Elements/ubuntubackup: Permission denied` means that in line 2 `sh` tried to execute `/media/fritzmedia/Elements/ubuntubackup` but failed to because it had no execution permission.

The problem is that you have a line break in the command handed to `shell_exec`. You should get rid of that and have everything on one line.

It would be even better if you didn't use `shell_exec` at all because it's prone to code injection in connection with potentially user-controlled values like `$_SESSION['lastbackup']`. You should at least pass it through `escapeshellcmd`. However, in this case your shell script can be re-implemented in PHP trivially.

Comment: if sh: 2 refers to the second statement does that mean that ht whole preceding if-fi block is considered to be one statement? Because /media..etc enters the stage in the cd "$1" statement.

Comment: The line break is a result of this forums editor; there is none in the original script.

Comment: I'm talking about about the first argument handed to `shell_exec` which executes `sh` which in turn is the origin of the error message. Your shell script is interpreted by `bash` so it can't be the origin. I removed the line break in your question but that is inconsistent with the error message. It implies that the command 1) contains at least two lines or one line break and 2) the first token on the second line (i. e. after the first line break) is `/media/fritzmedia/Elements/ubuntubackup`. Please double-check that there really is no line break in your source code in this command string.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was indeed the problem. Now I can start fousing on the script itself ;-)

Comment: Sorry to bother again but I don't see a "0" nor a (grey) checkbox. The answer was nevertheless extremely useful.